# Lazy-loading visible items in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, lazy-loading

I have a listview which uses the following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="Display" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="#373737" Margin="0,0,350,0" BorderThickness="0" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="767" Height="88">
                    <Border Height="64" Width="64" Margin="12,12,0,12">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=album.albumart}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="300" Height="40" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=album.name}" 
                   Margin="10,-15,0,0" Width="300" Height="20" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   FontSize="14" Opacity="0.49"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=artistname}" 
                   Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="300"
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   FontSize="12" Opacity="0.49"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And I have about 400 objects with images (this takes quite a bit of memory)

Which are then displayed in each listviewitem.

Is there any way for the listview to tell items to load their image from a cache I have based on which objects are visible in the listview instead of having all the images loaded all the time, which, as previously said takes quite a bit of memory.

Hope you guys understand what I'm on about, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this with the default ListView as-is. You could maybe accomplish this with JavaScript.

Comment: @Jason: Maybe my knowledge is a little outdated :D but does javascript really work in a C# WPF app ?

Comment: @Jason That really sucks... Guess the only option is to either make the pictures smaller or delete them all. Thanks though

Comment: Whoops! My bad! You still can't accomplish this with the out of the box WPF ListView. Might have to look into something like RadControls (http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx).

Comment: @Tokfrans, what is the type of `album.albumart`? Did you try to use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx). `ListView` by default uses virtualization which means it won't render items that aren't shown

Comment: @dkozl It's a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage (Think I got it right) But rendering isn't really the problem. Just loading all the items and filling each one with an image takes up quite a lot of memory.

Comment: @Tokfrans so you can try with `Lazy<T>` to load them only when they are needed and also, if your images are big and you don't need full resolution, you can use `BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth` and/or `BitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight` to say to what resolution they will be decoded in memory to save space

Comment: @dkozl Yeah I will read up on Lazy<T>, thank you. The DecodePixelHeight I've already been using. The thing is that I really want quite a big preview of the images (64x64).

Comment: @Jason I'm sorry, you have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this solution with my pictures folder containing more than 3500 pictures in high resolution. Memory usage peaked at 120MB with furious scrolling which seemed to trigger garbage collection and reduced memory to about 50MB.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Height="64" Width="64">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage
                            DecodePixelHeight="64"
                            DecodePixelWidth="64"
                            UriSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
                            CreateOptions="DelayCreation" 
                            CacheOption="None"  />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICollectionView Images { get; private set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
        }
        public void LoadImages()
        {
            var folder = @"C:\Users\lrved_000\Pictures";
            var photos = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.jpg",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            Images = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(photos);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Images");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gives me InvalidOperationException, always complaining that the UriSource or StreamSource should be set (although you are obviously providing a UriSource). VS2022, .Net 6.